# Valid JSON or JavaScript object to parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have a long polling operation that posts new objects as a JSON just fine, but while getting the updates returning an object, it seems like there is a not-valid JavaScript object I can't parse with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and since it's not valid JavaScript object I can't reach in. Here is `console.log` I got with the update:

```
{'body': 'hello world', 'html': '\n<div class="message" id="md1f1cdab-3c3a-4dfe-b268-834aa9981dec"><b>burakdede: </b>hello world</div>\n', 'from': 'burakdede', 'id': 'd1f1cdab-3c3a-4dfe-b268-834aa9981dec'}
```

Before the response comes out, I am using `eval("(" + response + ")")` to turn it into a JavaScript object. A show message is used for both posting a new message and getting updates. It works fine with the new posting, but it gives an error when the response comes out.

```
var updater = {
    errorSleepTime: 500,

    poll: function() {
        var args = {"_xsrf": getCookie("_xsrf")};
        args.listing_id = $(".action").attr("id");

        $.ajax({url: "/a/message/updates", type: "POST", dataType: "text",
                data: $.param(args), success: updater.onSuccess,
                error: updater.onError});
    },

    onSuccess: function(response) {
        try {
            updater.newMessages(eval("(" + response + ")"));
        } catch (e) {
            updater.onError();
            return;
        }
        updater.errorSleepTime = 500;
        window.setTimeout(updater.poll, 0);
    },

    onError: function(response) {
        updater.errorSleepTime *= 2;
        console.log("Poll error; sleeping for", updater.errorSleepTime, "ms");
        window.setTimeout(updater.poll, updater.errorSleepTime);
    },

    newMessages: function(response) {
        if (!response.messages) return;
        var messages = response.messages;
        //console.log(messages.length, "new messages, message is :", messages);
        updater.showMessage(messages);
    },

    showMessage: function(message) {
        var existing = $("#m" + message.id);
        if (existing.length > 0)return;
        var node = $(message.html);
        node.hide();
        $("#inbox").append(node);
        node.slideDown();
    },
};

function newMessage(form) {
    var message = form.formToDict();
    var disabled = form.find("input[type=submit]");
    disabled.disable();

    $.postJSON("/a/message/new", message, function(response) {
        updater.showMessage(response);
        if (message.id) {
            form.parent().remove();
        } else {
            form.find("input[type=text]").val("").select();
            disabled.enable();
        }
    });
}
```

---

Rather than fixing on the client side, I fixed the server side code and it is now working. The problem was that it could not produce proper JSON.

Comment: What kind of error do you get and where?

Answer (score 1):

Specify dataType = 'json' instead of 'text'. jQuery will handle an invalid response for you.

Comment: you mean poll function cause both of ajax queries have dataType=text ?

Comment: I mean that why don't use `dataType: "json"`, then the response is an object so that you can use directly response.body, response.html,... And (I think) there is a chance that jQuery handles invalid reponses for you.

Answer (score 0):

JSON object properties need to be wrapped inside double-quotes to be valid. Look at the definition of the **value** in [http://json.org](http://A%20value%20can%20be%20a%20string%20in%20double%20quotes,%20or%20a%20number,%20or%20true%20or%20false%20or%20null,%20or%20an%20object%20or%20an%20array.%20These%20structures%20can%20be%20nested.).

Comment: Are you generating the JSON? Then simply instead of creating something like `{name: 'saeed'}` or `{age: 23}`, etc., create something like `{"name": "saeed", "age": "23"}`. In other words, wrap all property names and all values with double-quotes. This is the safest way.

Comment: here is python side code for update it just return dictionary object which should be fine <code>self.finish(dict(messages=str(messages.body)))</code>

Comment: Actually the `eval` `Function` should handle that `Object` literal without a problem. JSON specifies double quotes for keys but this is not required in JavaScript per se.